# How to include libraries when compiling with Visual Studio on command line?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, command-line

I'm attempting to build a program with Visual Studio 2008 on the command line.
After reading [Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx).
I tried the following:

Run the vcvaralls.bat to setup the enviroment:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Wrote this simple C++ application:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <windows.h>
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBoxA(0,"Hello","Hello",MB_OK);

    return 0;
}`
```

And attempted to compile it:

```
cl /EHsc /GA simple.cpp
```

And this happens:

```
/out:simple.exe
simple.obj
simple.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function _WinMain@16
simple.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Which leads me to believe that I need to include user32.lib or similar.
I cant figure out from the visual studio manuals how to do that.

Comment: You might want to look for some [compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx) that seems to have something to do with linking.

Comment: I've often found it helpful to use the Visual Studio IDE. Once I get my project to build in there, I can go to one of the last tabs in the project properties and see all the command line options that it decided to put in, then copy/paste those options for my command line.

Comment: That's a great idea, jia103.

Comment: Open up help index and look for makefile wizard. You can also right click on the project name, click on properties, configuration manager and look the the command line options.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I would like to note that I spent a good couple  hours sifting through MSDN docs on the compiler before posting this question. It turns out there isn't a special option, you just include the library name along with source files. Which was not what I expected and therefore wasn't looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to use MessageBox you need to link at least with User32.lib, as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . Use:

```
cl /EHsc /GA /MT simple.cpp User32.lib
```

/MT chooses the Run-time library. In this example I used multi-threaded static library.

Comment: How do I do this with MSVC `link.exe` instead of `cl.exe`?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, `MessagBoxA` is defined in `User32.lib` and you need to link your code with it. You can provide the linker options to the `CL` compiler and it will pass it to the linker. All you need to do is to add the `User32.lib` to your compilation string: `cl /EHsc /GA simple.cpp User32.lib`